# Receive PostMessage messages for MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I have a dialog where the user is able to enter information and then press the Go button. When they press this button I disable the form elements (buttons etc) and create a worker thread using `AfxBeginThread( ... )`. Once the worker thread has completed I want it to send a message to the UI thread so as to re-enable the form. I am using `::PostMessage( ... )` to send the message, but I can't find how to intercept these messages.

i've searched online ([Link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807945/mfc-data-forwarding-to-main-thread-via-postmessage), [Link #2](http://computer-programming-forum.com/80-microsoft-visual-c-vc/ed34de15b3697a87.htm), [Link #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719902/postmessage-from-workerthread-to-main-window-in-mfc)) but I can't find an understandable example of the code to implement my own message listener. In the header I can see some crazy define statements (started with `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()`) which looks like it may have something to do with it, but I can't figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you use a message from the [`WM_APP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930(v=vs.85).aspx) range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message map is a table. For each message you are interested in it contains the message and a function pointer to the message handler function. To add a custom message to the map you add an ON_MESSAGE entry to the table. A tutorial example of doing this from a worker thread is here:

http://vcfaq.mvps.org/mfc/12.htm

Comment: I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k35k2bfs.aspx and the article you linked to has an error a believe. It uses `UINT` and `LONG` where it should use `WPARAM` and `LPARAM`. The MSDN article I linked to worked. Thanks for the help though.